# ObjectContext not garbage collected

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We are running a very simple function in a console application that loops through databases and lists a table into a variable. Of course originally it did more but we stripped it down to just listing 1 table.

We noticed that on every new creation of `ObjectContext` the memory grows by about 5MB. We have a `using()` statement for it and even when doing `GC.Collect()` the memory doesn't get freed.

When we remove the listing of the table and just create new `ClassEntities` the memory stays really low.

We tried everything we could to destroy AND collect but to no avail, resulting into a memory use of over 1GB.

Here is the main program:

```
List < string > databases = (from x in admin_db.tblDbs select x.db_name).ToList();
foreach(var db_name in databases) {
    Console.WriteLine("Current db:" + db_name);
    var entityString = String.Format("metadata=<here we put the connection string>", db_name);
    using(ClassEntities db = new ClassEntities(entityString)) {
        try {
            List < tblDepartment > departments = db.tblDepartments.ToList();
            departments = null;
        } catch {}
    }
}
```

Then the ClassEntities (stripped down):

```
public partial class ClassEntities: ObjectContext {
    public ClassEntities(): base("name=ClassEntities", "ClassEntities") {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
    public ClassEntities(string connectionString): base(connectionString, "ClassEntities") {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
    public ClassEntities(EntityConnection connection): base(connection, "ClassEntities") {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
}
```

Any help or ideas would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything specific that would cause an issue. Thoughts: how many entries are in `databases`? How many records are there in `tblDepartments`? Note that the garbage collector doesn't necessarily free up memory immediately at the end of the `using` block (the interval at which it runs is not very deterministic). Try using a memory profiler, it might help.

Comment: Also, calling GC.Collect() does not *force* a garbage collection; it just flags the object for collection the next time GC runs.  If you are running it in debug mode, you also may see some odd behavior with GC.  Finally, note that GC may not run if your process is not under memory pressure--you may see what looks like inflated memory that will never actually cause a problem.  All that said, >1GB does seem odd for a process that only uses ~5MB at a time.

Comment: @PhilSandler: from the documentation for [`GC.Collect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx): "Forces an immediate garbage collection of all generations". I.e. `GC.Collect()` specifically _does_ force a garbage collection.

Comment: Ditto the suggestion to use a memory profiler. I note that `ObjectContext` encapsulates both a database connection and a cache manager. 1GB seems excessive even when connection pooling or some object cache is involved, but the best way to know for sure whether either of those things are causing problems is to use a memory profiler.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're right!  Looks like GC.Collect() changed between .Net 3.5 and 4.0.

Comment: Thanks everyone for thinking along. There are about 360 databases, so 360 * 5MB would explain the 1GB for sure.

Already did a memory profile on it, with these results:
http://screencast.com/t/ad7CdTS9aWL
http://screencast.com/t/Ow73uM7oxmk
http://screencast.com/t/fyPneP3HVi2N

Any thoughts?

Comment: Unless you need to modify the entities and save changes back, perhaps you could use AsNoTracking()?  It could be that events hooked up to the entities are keeping the object context in scope.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 conditions for an object to be garbage collected:

- It gone out of scope
- It is no more referenced elsewhere in the program

As your screencast shows you have circular references that prevent expected garbage collection.

Your list of items is referencing connections, that in return references your items (HorekoEntitiesNoLog)

Try the following:

- Identify the complete graph of object references that constitute your circular references objects graph.
- Identify and the entry point(s) of this graph.
- Clear the reference of any entry point of the graph.
- Call GC.Collect().

If the memory don't get freed after GC.Collect call, either your are missing entry points references clear or your graph is not complete.